# Scalatra, Atmosphere, and Receiving Multiple Messages

Tags: scala, akka, atmosphere, scalatra

I am just playing with Scalatra and Akka like the guide suggests http://www.scalatra.org/guides/async/atmosphere.html. I've modified the guid so that I'm passing an actor system into the Atmosphere client.

However, I would like to know how I can get messages from the actor system back down to the client.

I can't use the ask pattern because the actor system may send multiple messages to the client - not one. What should I do here?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [The Inbox](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/actors.html#The_Inbox).

Comment: I'm stuck with akka 2.1.4 unfortunately